# Chromatic Polynomial of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am computing the chromatic polynomial of the given graph, chromatic number, domination number and and independence number of the attached picture. I want to know if my answer is correct. if not, can you help me? Thank you.

- chromatic number is 2,
- independence number is 3,
- domination number is 3 and
- chromatic polynomial is $\lambda(\lambda-1)^2$.

[image]

Comment: The chromatic polynomial of a graph always has degree equal to the number of vertices of the graph.

Comment: Why do you think the independence number is $3$? There is an obvious larger independent set.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez So if i choose $\lambda$ for the vertex with degree 1 and $\lambda-1$ for the vertex of degree 3 adjacent to the vertex of degree 1 so the chromatic polynomial is $\lambda^6(\lambda-1)^6$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Casteels. I am confused in finding the independence set. The dominating set is 6. Am I correct?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez  $λ(λ−1)^6(λ−2)^5$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

The chromatic polynomial is clearly $(\lambda-1)^6f(\lambda)$, where $f(\lambda)$ is the chromatic polynomial of the 6-cycle. But to compute that polynomial, you have to apply the delete-contract formula three times, $$P(G,\lambda)=P(G-e,\lambda)-P(G/e,\lambda)$$ Alternatively, you can use induction to get a formula that works for all $n$-cycles, and then let $n=6$ (but you need the delete-contract formula to get the $n$-cycle formula, so it's a bit of a wash).

Comment: Thank you so much for the idea..